# Can I use use .last and get an ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called `Notification` and inheriting models `VoteNotification` and `CommentNotification`. I'm building a `summarize` feature which takes the last 50 notifications and condenses them based on similarities. My code uses a lot of `.where` statements to narrow down what I need at different points.

Doing `current_user.notifications.last(50)` returns an array

Doing `current_user.notifications` returns an ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy which is the ideal data type for what `.summarize` actually does

**My question is, is there a way to get a CollectionProxy while also limiting the scope of my initial query to the last 50 notifications?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use `.last`, but you can definitely get the "last" record as a collection proxy:

```
current_user.notifications.order('id desc').limit(1)
```

Or

```
current_user.notifications.order('created_at desc').limit(1)
```

Comment: Perfect. Limit was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Meagar